# Bootstrap 5 carousel indicator not showing up

Tags: carousel, bootstrap-5

I have checked my code up and down and cannot find the problem. I do not see any typos or other errors. Can someone please let me know where I went wrong? I just want the tabs at the bottom to be visible and interactive as they should. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 <!-- Main -->
<section id="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <img src="/mainpic.PNG" alt="Volcano"
         class="img-fluid" >
      </div>
      <div class="div col-6">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide"
        data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#myCarousel"
               data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#myCarousel"
               data-slide-to="1"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="div container">
                  <h1>Activity</h1>
                  <p>Fun DIY activites that will entertain and educate your little ones</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>              
              <div class="carousel-item">
              <div class="div container">
                <h1>Activity</h1>
                <p>Fun DIY activites that will entertain and educate your little ones</p>
                </a>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>              
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assum your are using Bootstrap v5.2+. As Bootstrap v5+, `data-bs-ride` instead of `data-ride`, On the carouse indicator, `data-bs-target` instead of `data-target`. you just change `data-target` to `data-bs-target` and `data-ride` to `data-bs-ride` to fix it.

you can visit this demo: https://fastbootstrap.com/components/carousel/#with-indicators